# Type of i+"abc" in Java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I'm invoking

```
sb.append(i+"\n");
```

where

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
int i.
```

What is **i+"\n"** cast to here-- a **String**, a **StringBuffer**, **CharSequence**, character array, ...?

**StringBuilder** has **append()** each taking a param which is an **Object**, a **String**, a **StringBuilder** (this one is a private method),  a **StringBuffer**, a **CharSequence** parameter, character array, .. among others. I'm trying to find out which of these being invoked-- looking to avoid the call on **String** param for fast processing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Writing `sb.append(i); sb.append('\n');` will be equivalent.  I'd guess it will be faster since no intermediate `String` object would have to be created, but we wouldn't know for sure without running some tests.

Comment: It may be faster ... many JVM implementations perform String concatenation by using an intermediate StringBuilder for performance reasons (though I am not sure they would do it with two arguments).  If so, the concatenated argument could be slower ... but I can't imagine that the difference would be at all important in practice.

Answer (score 8):

Whenever the operator `+` is applied to a `String` and a variable of any other type, you have `String` concatenation. The value of `i + "\n"` is a `String`.

The [java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) covers this

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string
>   conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a
>   string at run time. **The result of string concatenation is a reference to a String object that is the concatenation of the two operand strings.** The characters of the left-hand operand precede the characters of the right-hand operand in the newly created string.

Therefore the `append()` method being called is the one which accepts a [`String` argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.String%29).

As @scottb comments, Java first converts the objects involved in a `String` concatenation into `String` objects. [This is described in the JLS chapter on `String` conversion.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11) Primitives are unboxed to their wrapper types. If the reference is anything other than `null`, the `toString()` method is called on the referenced object. If the reference is `null`, then the `String` `"null"` is used.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the representation of the non-string object is determined by calling its `toString()` method.  If the non-String item is a primitive, it is first autoboxed and then the `toString()` method of that is invoked.  This is one of the reasons why it is a good idea to override the `toString()` method in your own classes.